# spliting row to multiple columns in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

i have a table called hist having 31 columns

```
emi_id work1 sal1 work2 sal2      work3 sal3   work4 sal4 .....work15 sal15
100    wiring 1000  carpentry  2000 painting 3000......
```

i want to display as

```
100  wiring     1000
100  corpentry  2000
100  painting   3000
.
.
.
.
100 business    5000
```

how can i achieve this in oracle sql query

tried connect by but that is not permitted in my work environment

Comment: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/UNPIVOT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNPIVOT` on pairs of columns:

**Oracle Setup**:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( emi_id, work1, sal1, work2, sal2, work3, sal3, work4, sal4, work15, sal15 ) AS
SELECT 100, 'wiring', 1000, 'carpentry', 2000, 'painting', 3000, 'xyz', 4000, 'business', 15000 FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT ( ( work, sal ) FOR key IN (
  ( work1,  sal1  ) AS  1,
  ( work2,  sal2  ) AS  2,
  ( work3,  sal3  ) AS  3,
  ( work4,  sal4  ) AS  4,
  -- ...
  ( work15, sal15 ) AS 15
) )
```

**Output**:

> ```
> EMI_ID | KEY | WORK      |   SAL
> -----: | --: | :-------- | ----:
>    100 |   1 | wiring    |  1000
>    100 |   2 | carpentry |  2000
>    100 |   3 | painting  |  3000
>    100 |   4 | xyz       |  4000
>    100 |  15 | business  | 15000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e3b558a4b044a93cff425eb741844108)*